# Stdin Not Working As Intended [Python]

Tags: python, stdin

I'm running through some exercises in Python right now, including a simple line counter that can take input from the command line or stdin:

```
#### line_count1.py ####

import sys

def count_lines(file):
    n = 0
    for line in file:
        n = n + 1
    return n

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("Needs stdin")
    file = sys.stdin
else:
    print("File given at command line")
    file = open(sys.argv[1])

print (count_lines(file))
```

If I enter a file at the command line, ie **python line_count1.py file_with_4_lines.txt**, it works great, and I get the output:

```
File given at command line
4
```

However, if I enter it so that it DOES need stdin via **python line_count1.py**, I get the following output:

```
Needs stdin
_
```

But never actually does anything with my stdin entry. I can enter **file_with_4_lines.txt**, but then it just takes it and waits for me to input another stdin line, never breaking out until I have to kill the code in Task Manager.

What would be causing this to happen? From my understanding, as soon as I enter something for stdin that should trigger the rest of the code to go through. But it's not. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you expecting it to read the contents of `file_with_4_lines.txt` when you type `file_with_4_lines.txt` in the `stdin` case? Cause that's not how `stdin` works...

Comment: It's supposed to equate the file variable with stdin, which is then used in count_lines(file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to your code, but related to the `stdin` read behaviour on a terminal. See the following post for more information: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-signal-the-end-of-stdin-input.

EDIT:
As @Chase said, the key to terminate stdin on window is `Ctrl+Z`, and on linux it is `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve it, entering file_with_4_lines.txt ^D doesn't exit stdin, and neither does file_with_4_lines.txt, then ^D on the next line.

Comment: TO FUTURE READERS: The problem was that I'm on Windows, not Linux. Windows ends with Ctrl+Z, not Ctrl+D.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to accept a filename from `stdin` if not given at the command line, when what you're doing right now is attempting to count `stdin` itself.

If the goal is to process a given file, where the name comes from either `stdin` or the command line, then the code should be changed to:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    # Prompt for and read a single line from stdin to get the desired file name
    filename = input("Needs stdin")  # On Py2, use raw_input, not input
else:
    print("File given at command line")
    # Use argument as filename
    filename = sys.argv[1]

# Open the name provided at stdin or command line
# Use with statement so it's properly closed when you're done
with open(filename) as file:
    print(count_lines(file))
```